# Higher order differentials of Bockstein spectral sequence

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, spectral-sequences

The Bockstein SS is obtained from the exact sequence
$$0\to\mathbb{Z}\xrightarrow{2}\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/2\to 0$$
with $E_1^p=H^p(X,\mathbb{Z}/2)$ and the differential $d_1=Sq^1$.

How to identify the differentials $d_2$ for the $E_2$-page without knowing $H^*(X,\mathbb{Z})$ in advance?

Comment: $d_2$ is described by a “secondary” cohomology operation. You can read quite a bit about it in May’s _A general algebraic approach to Steenrod operations_ (whose title I may be imperfectly remembering), where the relevant operation is called $\beta_2$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The $E_1$ page does not tell you what the higher differentials will be, and you will have to know at least something about the integral cohomology.  Consider the case when $X$ is a Moore space $M(1,\mathbb{Z}/2^n)$ which you may prefer to think of as a circle with a disc attached via a $\times 2^n$ map.  In each case the $E_1$-page is the same, independent of $n$.  If $n=1$, the differential $d_1$ is non-zero.  If $n>1$ then the differential $d_1=Sq^1$ is zero.  The only differential that is non-zero in this case is $d^n$.  The cases $n=2,3,4,\ldots$ cannot be distinguished by knowing the $E_1$-page and $d_1$.

Comment: Is the $d_2$ some kind of cohomological operation for which some references could be found?

Comment: In general, higher differentials are higher cohomology operations, defined only on the kernels of the differentials below them. If $a$ is a mod-2 cohomology class with $Sq^1(a)=0$, this says that the coboundary $b$ of an integral lift of $a$ is divisible by~2.  The secondary operation in this case looks at $b/2$ as a mod-2 cocycle; this is defined only because $b$ was 0 mod-2.